# How to find data using join field in an entity with dynamic query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to query a property in a join table. The specification created is based on a dynamic query created based on the user request.

I am using dynamic specification creation based on the article below.
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-query-search-language-more-operations

The query works fine when I query the main elements. I want to query the elements in the join table using dynamic query. I get an error "Unable to locate Attribute"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {
@Getter @Setter
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Getter @Setter
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Setter @Getter
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "deviceId", nullable = false)
private DeviceEntity device;
}


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserEntity> {
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "device") 
public class DeviceEntity {
    @Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "serialNumber", nullable = false)
private String serialNumber;
}
```

1. How to query serialNumber from UserRepository using a dynamic query?
2. How to refer the serialNumber property in query? 
   "device.serialNumber" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the one below. The root will always point to the main entity and for the composit entities I need to get the path for that and add the element. I am using a mapper to map the entities for static mapping.

```
        protected void loadSearchParameterMappings() {
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("id", "id");
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("firstName", "firstName");
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("lastName", "lastName");
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("email", "email");
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("serialNumber", "device.serialNumber");
        getSearchParameterMappings().put("phoneNumber", "device.phoneNumber");
    }


 private Path<String> getParameterPath(final Root<T> root) {

        String[] keys = criteria.getKey().split("\\.");

        Path<String> path = null;

        for (String key : keys) {
            path = (path != null) ? path.get(key) : root.get(key);
            // verify all the mappings are done correctly or this mapping is not supported
            if (path == null) {
                throw new 
InvalidSearchParameterException(ErrorCode.INVALID_SEARCH_PARAM, key);
            }
        }

        if (path == null) {
            throw new InvalidSearchParameterException(ErrorCode.INVALID_SEARCH_PARAM, criteria.getKey());
        }

        return path;
    }
```

Comment: It make some sense but can you elaborate how to use with dyanamic query structure one stated with the post link thanks in advance...!!

Comment: Second doubt is how can we get path here as I am getting null

Answer (score 0):

You Join to join DeviceEntity

```
    Join<DeviceEntity, Site> device = root.join("device");
    return Specification.where(cb.equal(device.get("serialNumber"), deviceSerialNumber))
.and(cb.equal("serialNumber"), serialNumber))
```